# TabBar Badge Events and changing

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, badge

I have a tabbar, with a default badge count of 6. When a user changes the value of a button on the tab view, I would like the badge to adjust. -1 or +1. All the buttons are set to red, if the user changes the value to green, then the badge goes down to 5. If the go from green to red, then the badge adds 1 to 6 and so on. Is there an event to handle this, or do I need to write a method. Could someone please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try using the delegate method of UITabbarController

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

or either try to call it manually ....& set the badge,as per your wish.

Hope that could solve your problem.